# Struggling with font size of Tex Gyre

Tags: xetex, tex-gyre-math

I am working on my first XeLaTeX project and I am still struggling with the font settings. I defined a new math font for a specific section `unittable`:

```
\setmathfont[version=unittable,SizeFeatures={Size=9}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

So my plan is, to have TeX Gyre Pagella in font size 9pt for the section defined by `\mathversion{unittable}`. Unfortunately (and surprising to me), the size 9pt doesn't exist for TeX Gyre Pagella and I get the following warning:

`LaTeX Font: Font shape 'TU/TeXGyrePagellaMath(1)/m/n' in size <10.95> not available size <9> substituted.`

Is there any way around, e.g. scaling or using a font clone, which supports 9pt? Or is there an overview, of which font sizes are available for TeX Gyre Pagella? thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add a complete short document that shows the problem?   My reading of the error message above suggests it *has* got 9pt, but not 10.95pt....

Comment: there is only one font and is scalable to all sizes so it's just a matter of getting the tex declarations in order, not getting a different font.

Comment: If the fonts are genuinely not scaling correctly in relation to each other, you could add the command `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}` after `\setmainfont`.

Comment: @Thruston, the message is a bit confusing, but it's like I said, 9pt is missing, 10.95pt was used instead.

Comment: @Davislor, no it also really replaces the font, it's not actually in 9pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can you help me, how I can scale it to 9pt? I set 9pt from e.g. my graphics, and I would like to have the same size in my document, but with a "scale factor" is can just make a rough estimate, right? Or is there an option "scale to 9pt"?

Comment: I'd need to check, I suspect that you are forcing it to use 9pt at all sizes so you are being warned that 11pt (10.95pt) is using 9pt.  fontspec does have a scale option if I recall correctly. You want to scale by 0.9 not use 9pt at all sizes, I assume.

Comment: why is a scale a rough estimate? In the standard classes If your `\normalsize` is 10pt then `\small` is 9pt so you could simply use `\small` or scale by 0.9 is exactly 9pt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, nevermind, it came from misunderstanding of predefined font sizes. I tried the font scaling and the result is sastifying, thanks a lot.

Comment: can you self-answer with whatever worked, to get the question off the "unanswered" list and to help any following readers, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Scaling argument worked properley:

```
\setmathfont[version=unittable,Scale=0.822]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
```

where I calculaed the ratio from the original and the expected font-size: `0.822 = 9/10.95`